# can't make work audio tag html5

Tags: php, html, laravel

must be stupid error-> can't play song by html5 tag i don't know it helps: i use laravel 5.4, apache as webserver, the file of page is user_song.blade.php format

```
 <audio preload src="Starset_-_My-Demons-1.mp3" controls="controls" >
                            Your browser does not support HTML5 Audio!
                        </audio>
```

the file really exists and when i use it in single html page with that file it really works, plays, but in my laravel project **NO**. I ll appreciate if u help

Comment: Is the file in the right place relative to the path in Laravel? E.g. if you're looking at https://example.com/somepage the browser will expect the file to be in `public/somepage/Starset_-_My-Demons-1.mp3` as it assumes `somepage` is a directory

Comment: Changed the path, still bad

Comment: If you look at the [network tab in your browsers developer tools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network-performance/) does it show the path of the mp3 it's trying to download? It should be red with a status of 404.

Comment: Nope, everything is good